# Schmidt decomposition problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm having a problem in implementing the following problem:

I have a quantum state so defined:

$\left| \Psi\right>=\int \mathcal{A}(\omega_1,\omega_2)\hat{a}^\dagger_H(\omega_1)\hat{a}^\dagger_V(\omega_2) \left| 0\right>_H \left| 0\right>_V d\omega_1 d\omega_2$

where I know the function $\mathcal{A}(\omega_1,\omega_2)$.

I have to check the factorability of $\mathcal{A}(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ by performing a Schmidt decomposition, i.e. solving the following problem:

$\mathcal{A}(\omega_1,\omega_2) = \sum_n \sqrt{\lambda_n} \psi_n(\omega_1)\phi_n(\omega_2)$

where $\lambda_n$, $\psi_n$ and $\phi_n$ are solution of the integral eigen-
value equations:

$\int K_1(\omega,\omega')\psi_n(\omega')d\omega' = \lambda_n \psi_n(\omega)$

$\int K_2(\omega,\omega')\phi_n(\omega')d\omega' = \lambda_n \phi_n(\omega)$

$ K_1(\omega,\omega')=\int \mathcal{A}(\omega,\omega_2) \mathcal{A}^*(\omega',\omega_2)d\omega_2$

$ K_2(\omega,\omega')=\int \mathcal{A}(\omega_1,\omega) \mathcal{A}^*(\omega_1,\omega')d\omega_1$

I never approached a problem like this from a computational point of view, and I've no idea about a possible solution. Any help or idea is welcome!

The following step would be to have an esperimental set of data which should be the "measured"  $\mathcal{A}(\omega_1,\omega_2)$, and to perform the decomposition on this data to find the corresponding Schmidt decomposition. But that is another problm, let's go step by step :D

Comment: and what has to do this with Mathematica software? Seems to me like this should be migrated to another site.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by using double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: Well yes, probably you are right. I wrote in Mathematica site because I have the whole program in Mathematica and I'd like to add the part I asked here in that program, so I needed ideas to implement it using Mathematica code.